# Is it a good practice to enable file compression for all file types on a webserver?

Tags: file, svg, webserver, compression

Do you think if it is a good practice to make file compression on all file types on a webserver?

I was going to enable the file compression on SVG files to reduce the wait time for downloading of the font files and also the other text base file types and I was thinking if it is a good practice to enable the file compression on all types of the files or not.

Does it have a bad effect on performance or something?

Please let me know what your experience is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web for hours, I found these two resources:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-httpcomp/

and

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e23435/enablecomp.htm

form first resource:

> HTTP compression, a recommendation of the HTTP 1.1 protocol
>   specification for improved page download time

and from second resource:

> Regular text and most non-image content are well suited for
>   compression. Text files can typically be compressed by 70% or more.
>   Compression can save significant bandwidth and enable faster browser
>   response times. The effect is negligible in most high speed LAN
>   environments, but is quite noticeable for users on slow WAN
>   connections.
>
> Compression is not recommended for files that are already compressed.
>   A partial list includes these types of files:
>
> zip
>
> PDF
>
> exe
>
> image files
>
> Compressing these file types using mod_deflate can actually increase
>   their size or corrupt the files.
>
> There are 9 levels of compression available when using mod_deflate.
>   The difference between the default level (6) and the maximum
>   compression level (9) is minimal, and the cost in extra CPU time
>   necessary to process the higher compression level is significant and
>   ultimately not beneficial. For this reason, you should use the default
>   compression level.

So here is the list I prefer to compress on my server side:

> **/**xml* (Including application/xhtml+xml | application/xml | application/xml-dtd | image/svg+xml and...)
>
> text/* (Including text/html | text/javascript and ...)
>
> message/* (Including message/http | message/rfc822 and ...) from this page's code sample http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression
>
> application/ecmascript | application/json | application/javascript

This may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Compressing loseless data will give you good results. But compressing lossy files will not, and most likely will cost more since use of compression on those files will only result in wasted clock cycles (lossy files are pre-compressed video, audio and image files -- jpg, mp3, avi.. etc).

Loseless data will include text, source-code, any bitmap images (bmp), executables, csv files.. etc. They will have good compression ratio thus compressing them will give good results (result in higher throughput and energy efficiency). You should also consider to use light-weight compression algorithms (gzip and especially lzop if possible).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is generally a good idea.  Computers can usually decompress bytes faster than they can fetch them over the net.

If you are not sure, why not use something like PageSpeed to analyse the best course of action.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Comment: I know that compression is a good method for web serving the files but there are file formats that may grow bigger when compressed as they could not be compressed and that forces the system (webserver) to do more cpu cycles. What I want to know is if applying the compression on all the file types is proved to be better or to apply it is specific file types.

Comment: Well I thought you were asking whether it was better to turn it on for everything rather than for nothing.  It sounded like you were reluctant to bother with picking and choosing filetypes.